# What it's the canonical way of interfacing DB's id with HTML id?

Tags: html, python-3.x, design-patterns, bottle

So I'm writing a simple web app. It has SQLite as the RDBMS, Python's bottle framework as server and rest is HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Now, we all know that HTML tags cannot have id(s) starting with a numeral. And using text/string as primary key in database would be hell.

Right now I'm converting DB id to string and adding an `_` before it so it renders correctly in HTML. And doing the reverse when DB needs to be updated. But my code doesn't look beautiful.

So what's the standard accepted way of making these two talk? Where should I implement the translator, in Python or in JavaScript? What background does this problem have in conventional computer science?

---

**Edit:** for those asking for more specificity

What it's the best way to ensure both model and view work correctly without monkey coding a `to` and `from` function everywhere (a programmer might forget to call it).

Also if you are trained in computer science at college or know super academic languages like Java or Haskell, what would be your approach.

Comment: Your question is far too broad for this platform. You need to ask a specific question about a specific problem.

Comment: @Rob - I agree, this question is broad, but then that's what *canonical* and *design-patterns* are for son. If you look up `canonical stackoverflow.com` on Google, you'd realise your mistake about calling my question "too broad" for this platform

Comment: You can't agree that it's too broad and then disagree that it's too broad at the same time. In addition, your edit is asking for opinion which is also off topic here.

Answer (score 0):

It was news to me that ids cannot start with a numeral, although I checked the [official reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and you are right.

In practice I have used integers and uuids as element ids for years across many browsers and never had a problem with the browser rendering it or accessing it via JavaScript.

So my answer is just to ignore it.

**EDIT**

In response to the downvote - just try this

```
<body>
    <p id="1" onclick="alertme()">This is some text</p>
    <script>
        function alertme(){alert(document.getElementById('1').innerText);}
    </script>
</body>
```

as a plain html file opened in various browsers and using developer tools.

Not one browser complains about it. (Firefox complains there is no html tag or encoding but there you go). Everything works. This is simple practical advice for the real world.

Comment: Absolutely! You should always ignore web standards written by the browser vendors themselves. After all, what do they know?

Comment: @Rob - Real world advice!

Comment: Browsers are required by the specification to do the best they can with bad markup and code. It would be far smarter to follow the specification rather than let browsers guess your intentions. Your answer is horrible.

Comment: @aim100k Good point about the css - however in practice you would never apply styling to elements based on their database id

Comment: @ste-fu consider the case of showing details (change view) on hover or on click by user.

Comment: @aim100k but almost by definition, database items are within a list, therefore you would use a css class in combination

Comment: @aim100k And who do you think the writers and editors of the W3C standard are composed of? Browser vendors. Currently, Microsoft, Google and Apple